# Clone a GIT repository with NGit in VB.net

Tags: .net, git, jgit, ngit

My objective is to perform clone and pull operations on a `GIT` repository through `.NET` code. When cloning, I specifically want to clone a particular branch. If a particular repository is already cloned but with a different branch, then I would like to be able to know it as well.

I had implemented this with `jGit` in Java successfully, but now I need to develop a similar tool in `.NET` and I prefer using `NGit` since it is a direct port of `jGIT` library.

However, though I use the exact methods passing the relevant parameters to the clone method in `NGit`, I don't see repository getting downloaded. Below is my code:

```
Dim branches As List(Of String) = New List(Of String) From {branch}
Git.CloneRepository.
    SetURI(cloneURL).
    SetDirectory(New Sharpen.FilePath(downloadFolder)).  
    SetBranchesToClone(branches).
    SetCredentialsProvider(New UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider(userID, userPwd)).
    SetBranch(branch).
    Call()
```

When I run this, it takes few seconds and there are no errors. But in the download folder I see there is only a `.git` folder with some meta data and the source files are not downloaded. If I remove `SetBranchesToClone` and `SetBranch` methods from the above code, it downloads files successfully from master branch.

Why doesn't it work when branch info is provided?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that while in jGit you can use the exact branch name like `MyBranch`, in case of NGit you need to pass `refs/heads/MyBranch` for it work. Apparently though nGit claims to be an automatic port of jGit, there are some minor differences in how they work.